# Able to find Active Directory group using directory search but group does not exist in left window panel domain tree

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a single 2008 R2 DC. We're trying to locate Builtin groups that no longer visually appear in the Builtin group folder in the domain tree in the left panel of the active directory users and computers tool. We tried the directory search, thinking that maybe those groups were just moved to another OU or folder and the search found them. However, the search claims that those groups are still in the Builtin folder when they are not.

Can anyone please explain where our "missing" groups actually are or what is going on with the search?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean. Maybe post an image of what you see?

Comment: Does the user account have permissions to view that folder?

Comment: joeqwerty, sorry, can't send a screenshot from our server, but here's a link to a pic that should help clarify:

https://tr3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2008/05/21/2b183e98-c3b9-11e2-bc00-02911874f8c8/a-server-manager-aduc.png

So when we open the BuiltIn groups container, nothing's there (someone must've moved/deleted them we thought). So we did a search and found some of those BuiltIn groups like 'Administrators', but according to the search, they are in the BuiltIn container, which they visually are not.

Comment: Davidw, yes, we're using an account with administrator privileges. It's the same account we always use to add, edit, delete users and groups. It's an old DC we inherited that's been picked apart by many different admins over many years and we're trying to get it cleaned up

Comment: Wondering if this could potentially be a GPO doing this?

Comment: Found the issue. Someone had set the view filtering options to show only USERS, nothing else. Thus why no security groups or anything else could be seen or found (except through search).

Answer (score 0):

In the Active Directory Users and Computers menu, go to View > Filter Options.

Select the top radio button "Show all types of objects". Eveything in AD should appear.

To specify only select types of AD objects, select the second radio button "Show only the following types of objects" and then select checkboxes below.